# Are integers systematically converted to long in Access VBA as well?

Tags: vba, ms-access, type-conversion, integer, long-integer

In the recent versions Excel VBA, the VB engine converts an Integer data type to Long while maintaining the Integer overflow limits.  So as a rule of thumb, I always use Long values in Excel VBA.

Does anyone know if the same is true in Access?  I realize it's the same engine with different references, but as I move more into Access VBA I never want to assume.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your assumptions.

See the following:

```
Sub checkForVariableMemorySizes()

    Dim arrInt() As Integer
    ReDim arrInt(1 To 2)
    arrInt(1) = 12
    arrInt(2) = 456

    Dim arrLong() As Long
    ReDim arrLong(1 To 2)
    arrLong(1) = 12
    arrLong(2) = 456


    Debug.Print "Integer size:" & vbTab & VarPtr(arrInt(2)) - VarPtr(arrInt(1)) & vbTab & vbTab & "Typename: " & TypeName(arrInt(2))
    Debug.Print "Long size:" & vbTab & vbTab & VarPtr(arrLong(2)) - VarPtr(arrLong(1)) & vbTab & vbTab & "Typename: " & TypeName(arrLong(2))

End Sub
```

this outputs:

```
Integer size:   2       Typename: Integer
Long size:      4       Typename: Long
```

You will notice that the sizes are actually different (measured by number of bytes each is incremented, 2 and 4 respectively).

Identical behavior exists for this automatic conversion as the same output from both Excel and Access (I am using Access/Excel 2010 on 32-bit Windows 7). I would be very interested to see what this outputs in older versions.

Comment: I don't think I'm assuming based on the MS dev center, but at any rate the size of my variables isn't what concerns me. It's their performance.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the same in Access. 
If you are dealing with numbers larger than the limits of int, you need to use long. 
As just a side note, although excel VBA may do the conversion, it is not a good practice.

[MS Access Q&A - Overflow Error](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/472271-overflow-error)

Comment: Can you elaborate on your side note?  I've come across several speed trials that disagree with you.  Are you just referring to the visual interpretation of code?